# Finding distinct object in array by es6

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array like below

```
const data = [
    {
        name:'AAAA',
        group: 'A',
        age:10
    },
    {
        name:'ABCD',
        group: 'A',
        age:10
    },
    {
        name:'DJSHDJH',
        group: 'B',
        age:15
    },
    {
        name:'FJHF',
        group: 'B',
        age:20
    }
]
```

I want to find distinct data by `group` and `age` by `es6`

expected result

```
[
    {
        group: 'A',
        age: 10
    },
    {
        group: 'B',
        age: 15
    },
    {
        group: 'B',
        age: 20
    }
]
```

I tried using `[... new Set(data.map(x => {x.group, g.age}))]` but no chance

I know how to loop through data and find unique values, but I want to use `es6` functions

Comment: You want filter and  map or just reduce

Comment: @epascarello, what is in filter?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: @epascarello I know what is filter and how to use it, how does filter solve my problem? I need unique values by group and age

Comment: because you use to to loop over and filter out the unique groups and ages....

Comment: @epascarello Reducing would be more appropriate IMO.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `Object.values()` with `reduce()` to return array of values as result.

```js
const data = [{"name":"AAAA","group":"A","age":10},{"name":"ABCD","group":"A","age":10},{"name":"DJSHDJH","group":"B","age":15},{"name":"FJHF","group":"B","age":20}]

var result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, e) => (r[e.group + '|' + e.age] = {group: e.group, age: e.age}, r), {}))
console.log(result)
```

Another way of writing the same code as suggested by `@Jeremy Thille` is using **template literals** and **property value shorthand**

```js
const data = [{"name":"AAAA","group":"A","age":10},{"name":"ABCD","group":"A","age":10},{"name":"DJSHDJH","group":"B","age":15},{"name":"FJHF","group":"B","age":20}]

var result = Object.values(data.reduce(function(r, e) {
  let group = e.group, age = e.age;
  return r[`${group}|${age}`] = {group, age}, r
}, {}))

console.log(result)
```

You can also use ES6 parameter destructuring as suggested by `@gyre`.

```js
const data = [{"name":"AAAA","group":"A","age":10},{"name":"ABCD","group":"A","age":10},{"name":"DJSHDJH","group":"B","age":15},{"name":"FJHF","group":"B","age":20}]

var result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, {group, age}) => (r[group+'|'+age] = {group, age}, r), {}))
console.log(result)
```

Comment: `r[e.group + '|' + e.age]` is so ES5. Use `r[\`${e.group}|${e.age}\`]` but upvoted nonetheless

Comment: Can someone explain what the portion `, r` in `= {group: e.group, age: e.age}, r` is doing?

Comment: Comma operator will return the last item `(r, e) => { (r[e.group + '|' + e.age] = {group: e.group, age: e.age}; return r}`

Comment: You can also use the destructuring parameter `{ group, age }` in place of `e` to simplify the body of the reduction function

Comment: @gyre Thanks men, that's great.

Answer (score 2):

Utilizing a lookup table just like Nenad's code is the right way to do this job however just for a variety i include a solution by sorting and reducing which is obviously less efficient.

```js
var data   = [{"name":"AAAA","group":"A","age":10},
              {"name":"DJSHDJH","group":"B","age":15},
              {"name":"ABCD","group":"A","age":10},
              {"name":"FJHF","group":"B","age":20},
              {"name":"ABCD","group":"A","age":12},
              {"name":"SOLUS","group":"B","age":15},],
    result = data.sort((a,b) => a.group.localeCompare(b.group) || a.age - b.age)
                 .reduce((r,c,i) => i ? r[r.length-1].group == c.group && r[r.length-1].age == c.age ? r 
                                                                                                     : r.concat({group:c.group, age:c.age})
                                      : [{group:c.group, age:c.age}], []);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this, more readable but longer way is:

```
var filteredData = [];
data.forEach((item)=>{
    if(!filteredData.some(x=>x.group === item.group && x.age === item.age)){
        filteredData.push(item);
    }
});

// then you can change your result array if you want by using map
var result = filteredData.map(x=>{name:x.name,age:x.age});
```